# Hide Falang 1/2 flags from Falang flag module for few articles only

Tags: joomla, multilingual

I have Joomla site and installed Falang to translate content.

Now what i need is to disable particular language flag for particular article as that article translation is not available. How can i do that? May i have to use some other extension beside Falang?

For example: Article name is XYZ only have to display in ENG and PT lang. but i have ES lang installed on website. for XYZ article the ES flag will not display or will be in in-active mode. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would probably be a good question to ask on the joomla stackexchange site [joomla.se].